# How can I save the attribute named "x:SynchronousMode" to a xaml file?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, asynchronous

In our software, we can draw or edit shapes and save it as a xaml.

Then, we want to load it(this xaml file) asynchronously, we used `LoadAsync()` method to do this, now the question is we can write `x:SynchronousMode='Async'` to the file manually, but how can we save this attribute to a xaml file directly(when we serialize it)?

The [instruction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/aa346591%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) from MSDN:

> In order for LoadAsync to load XAML input asynchronously, the root
>   element in the XAML input must contain the attribute and value
>   x:SynchronousMode="Async".

Comment: How you are serializing your xaml  ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally,I didn't find the way to add the attribute to the object, then I used a tack-handed way to solve this problem by the following code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings);
XamlWriter.Save(Window, xmlWriter);
var str = sb.ToString().Insert(11, "assembly:SynchronousMode=\"Async\" ");
if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    FileStream tmp = File.Create(path);
    tmp.Close();
}
FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
sw.WriteLine(str);
sw.Flush();
sw.Close();
fs.Close();
```

Insert it to the string that we convert object into with XamlWriter directly, and then save the string as a xaml file.